# Getting list of controllers in app - good practice

Tags: angularjs

I need to have an array of tabs in my angular application with each tab having its own template and controller. Each controller is defiend as `app.controller('ctrlName'`... in its own separate file. In my parent controller, I have the following code snippet.

```
var ctrlHash = {};
console.log(app._invokeQueue)
for (var i = 0; i < app._invokeQueue.length; i++){
  ctrlHash[ app._invokeQueue[i][2][0] ] = app._invokeQueue[i][2][1][app._invokeQueue[i][2][1].length - 1];
}


$scope.tabs = [
  {
      ctrl :  ctrlHash['ctrl1'] 
    , heading : 'Tab 1'
  },
  {
      ctrl: ctrlHash['ctrl2']
    , heading: 'Tab 22'
  }
]
```

This works but I can't help but feel that it is very bad practice. Can anybody more experienced pipe in and tell me if this is okay to use for production or if there is a more elegant Angular way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: why do you need a reference to a controller like that?  What are you trying to achieve that isn't being done by setting ng-controller on a tab element?  I suppose you _could_ make a service (say MenuService) that you can inject each of your controllers into, spin up the menu object as needed, and then just inject that into your app.

Comment: I'm using angular bootstrap tabs and I need to have a button that goes "next tab/previous tab". If I declare the tab controllers in the html, I wont be able to go tabs[i].selected = true. Also can you explain your menu service suggestion? If I understand it correctly, for each tabCtrl, I inject the MenuService, and at the beginning of each tab controller I go `MenuService.addController('controllerName',this)` ?